# How to get just one item from ForeignKey Model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have below two models in my app,

```
class Question(models.Model):
   question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   question_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   q_pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Question Published')

   def __str__(self):
      return self.question_text


class Answer(models.Model):
   answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
   answer_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ans_auth')
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   a_pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Answer Published')

   def __str__(self):
      return self.answer_text
```

I want to show latest questions on home page in a list. Each item in list will show question text and one answer out of many posted for that particular question. I am able to show question text but I am not able to find a way to get the answer item for every question item in my view below,

```
def home(request):
   latest_question = Question.objects.order_by('-q_pub_date')[:15]
```

Comment: you could get the **answer** to a specific **question** with the [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) `question_instance.answer_set.all()` in views, `{{ question_instance.answer_set.all }}`

Comment: hey @Lemayzeur I just need one answer for every question in the result set.

Comment: SO you can select one question with `slice`, or `first`: `{{question_instance.answer_set.all.0 }}` `question_instance.answer_set.first()`

Comment: Thats right. Works, is there any other way to filter out on the basis of a condition? Like suppose if i add a new field votes to the `Question` and I want the answer which has highest votes?

Comment: A `property method` inside your question model will do it with just a condition like: `return self.answer_set.all().order_by('vote').last()`

Comment: Thats right. Seems legit. You can post both your comments as an answer so that I can accept them as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the **answer** to a specific **question** with the reverse relation `question_instance.answer_set.all()` in views, `{{ question_instance.answer_set.all }}` in templates.

To select one answer, you can use `slice`, or `first()`:

```
{{question_instance.answer_set.all.0 }} # templates

question_instance.answer_set.first() # views
```

> *If you want to add a new field `votes` to the **Question** and you want the **answer** which has highest votes?*

A property method inside your question model will do it like:

```
@property
def higher_answer(self):
    return self.answer_set.all().order_by('vote').last()
```

Comment: @vikasdevde , see the answer

Comment: Hey @Lemayzeur, the answer_set only returning answer_text, how do I get the answer_author as well in the same result set?

Comment: When you do `answer_set.all` you have access to a queryset, as you asked before, you only want one answer, so choose an instance from the queryset `answer_set.all().fisrt()` or `{{ answer_set.all.0 }}` in templates, then you have access to all attributes of Answer model : `answer_set.all().fisrt().answer_author` or `{{ answer_set.all.0.answer_author }}`

Comment: right, I did it same way but I guess I missed something, rewrote and working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Be careful with this approach! It leads to known N+1 problem: for each Question you will make request to database for Answer which can lead to performance issues! But of course with small amount of Questions it is okay, just remember about N+1..

Answer (score 1):

You can access all answers by using the `related_name`:

```
>>> question = Question.objects.get(question_text='random question')
>>> print(question.answer_set.all())
```

You can read more about this on: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: yeah I knew that after I did some search, but I just need one answer for every question that too in the same queryset along with the question text, so that I can iterate over them on my home page to show the data.